# Writing C++ "Scripts"

Tags: c++, design-patterns, coding-style, program-entry-point

I am a solo developer on a large C++ library that I use for research (I'm a PhD student). Let's say the library has a bunch of classes that implement cool algorithms: `Algorithm1`, `Algorithm2`, etc. I then write a bunch of C-style functions that are stand-alone "scripts" that use the library to either test the recently added functionality or to run simulations that produce plots that I then include in wonderfully-brilliant (I'm in denial) journal publications. The design of the library follows good software engineering principles (to the best of my knowledge and ability), but the "scripts" that link the library from `main.cpp` do not follow any principle except: "get the job done".

I now have over 300 such "scripts" in a single file (20,000+ lines of code). I have no problem with it, I remain very productive, and that's really the ultimate goal. But I wonder if this approach has major weaknesses that I just have learned to live with.

```
// File: main.cpp

#include <cool_library/algorithm1.h>
#include <cool_library/algorithm2.h> 
...
#include <cool_library/algorithmn.h> 

void script1() {
    // do stuff that uses some of the cool library's algorithms and data structures
    // but none of the other scriptX() functions
}

void script2() {
    // do stuff that uses some of the included algorithms and data structures
}

... 

// Main function where I comment in the *one* script I want to run.
int main() {
    // script1();
    // script2();
    // script3();
    ...
    script271();

    return 0;               
}
```

Edit 1: There are several goals that I have in this process:

- Minimize the time it takes to start a new script function.
- Make all old script functions available at my finger tips for search. So I can then copy and paste bits of those scripts into a new one. Remember this is *NOT* supposed to be good design for use by others.
- I don't care about the compilation time of the script file because it compiles in under a second as it is now with the 20,000 lines of code.

I use Emacs as my "IDE" by the way, in Linux, using the Autoconf/Automake/Libtool process for building the library and the scripts.

Edit 2: Based on the suggestions, I'm starting to wonder if part of the way to increase productivity in this scenario is not to restructure the code, but to customize/extend the functionality of the IDE (Emacs in my case).

Comment: What is your PhD subject? (in what domain)?? Do you want other people to use your library?

Comment: It's a collection of algorithms for optimizing various aspects of wireless networks. Here's an example paper I published: http://goo.gl/lRXtP I do want other people to use the library, but the "script" functions are not part of the library, they are basically individual examples of how to use the library.

Comment: Then, I think that my suggestion of using some real scripting language makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would split that huge file into 300 smaller ones: each would have just one `scriptNN()` and `main()` calling just it.

Now, when you have it compiled, you will have 300 small `scriptNN` executables (you may need to create appropriate `Makefile` for this though).

What's nice about this - now you can use these script executables as building blocks to be put or called by other scripts, like bash, python, perl, etc.

**EDIT** Explanation how this design allows to address your goals.

- *Time to start new script function* - simply copy one of existing files and tweak it a little.
- *Make all old script functions available at my finger tips for search* - emacs can do multi-file search across all other script files you have.
- *I don't care about the compilation time of the script file* - it does not matter then. But you will have all of them available to you at once, without editing one big `main()` and recompiling.

Answer (score 2):

Your example may be a good use case of [scripting language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language). To be more specific, you could all your `script*`  C++ functions glued to some interpreter, like [Lua](http://www.lua.org), [Python](http://www.python.org/), [Ocaml](http://caml.inria.fr/ocaml/), [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) etc... and have your test cases be written in the scripting language.

All scripting languages enable you to glue your C (hence also C++) functions. 
For Lua, see its [Lua API](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#4) chapter. For Python, see its [Extending & Embedding Python](http://docs.python.org/3/extending/) section. For Ocaml, see [Interfacing C with OCaml](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual033.html) section. For Guile, see [Programming in C](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Programming-in-C.html) chapter.

You may wish to embed the interpreter inside your `main` function, or you could extend the existing interpreter with your new `C++` functions (hence using some `main` provided by the interpreter).

Notice that using some scripting language may have a profound impact on the design and architecture of your library and software

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "to be more specific" part of your suggestion? Can you give an example of how to connect C++ with a scripting language.

Comment: @LexFridman: I added specific references to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with it, and it works for you, just stick with it. You said you are the only developer, then just do whatever you want. I always spend too much time thinking about things like this for my projects :P. I've learned to just focus on the important and productive things. Theoretical things only work in theory...

Answer (score 1):

All the suggested answers are good and you can even combine them. Just to add my 5 cents: your execution flow fits exactly into [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) and [Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) design patterns. You may want to look at their benefits, but it's a question of benefit vs. investment.